# Can make/cause a scene be used in this way?

Tags: phrase-usage

Say a waiter talks to some costumers, something happens, then he crouches down and laughs.

Can we say that he made/caused a scene? Even though he didn't shout or [display anger](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-scene)?

Comment: You might get more targeted answers if you explained more about the context. "Something happens"? And I have no idea why he "crouches down." We can't parse human behavior from something so inexplicable...

Comment: Do you really mean people who make clothing… or customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would not use "make a scene" this way.  *Making a scene* is about a disruptive outburst, or a commotion: something that creates a disturbance.  Simply laughing (presumably in a restaurant?) isn't "making a scene".

Comment: Well... depends how you laugh! A simple, normal, conversational laugh is hardly disruptive. But if you laugh so loudly or long that it disturbs others, it could qualify.

Comment: There is the bit about crouching down; the laughing would call attention to the strange behaviour of crouching down, and I think that would be a scene - something that gets attention.

Comment: One can also *make a scene* in subtle ways.  Parking your purple, Brittany Spears themed, Kia Sportage at a 16 year old's birthday party would qualify as making scene if the party attendees gathered round and admired the compact, sport SUV.